# Quick click button in Phonegap

Tags: android, button, cordova, click

I started to learn phonegap and I want to try make a simple application using a button and a text. I've tried do it and it works on my Android.
The problem is, there are delay when I clicked the button. Is there any solution to remove the delay and make it like a flash button that can be clicked rapidly?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FastClick is a simple, easy-to-use library for eliminating the 300ms delay between a physical tap and the firing of a click event on mobile browsers.

The aim is to make your application feel less laggy and more responsive while avoiding any interference with your current logic.

[Official Page](http://ftlabs.github.io/fastclick/)

You must include it in the page:

```
<script type='application/javascript' src='/path/to/fastclick.js'></script>
```

Then call it after the DOM is loaded:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    new FastClick(document.body);
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, I will try to use it :)